# How to Adjust the Zoom effect of an Image View?

Tags: android, android-layout, matrix, android-view

I am creating a small application that allows you to zoom a `ImageView`. When I use an image that will fit on every contour of the layout (all sides of the image are seen and covers the entire layout), all parties image no longer appears on layout like having zoom in addition to the zoom effect when the XML code I write `android:scaleType = "matrix"`. But I want the image will fit on layout in actual size the user can zoom. I think it's the fact that I use `scaleType = "matrix"` because when I put `scaleType = "centerinside"` l image appears completely as I want but there is more to zoom image effect. I wonder if I need to change my code when I use java also overcharged `scaleType = "centerinside"`.

Comment: Not enough study before asking a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add zoom effects to your imageview by adding this library to your project [**PhotoView**](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

***from docs***

> Implementation of ImageView for Android that supports zooming, by
>   various touch gestures.

if you are using **android studio** following can be useful to add this library:

**Usage**

in your app's `Build.gradle` add following code

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
}
```

then in your `activity.xml` replace your regular **Imageview** with following

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Remember you don't have to change **`Activity.java`**.it works fine with regular **imageview**

[**sample**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.photoview.sample)

Comment: YOU think that i can just add zoom effect if i use this library and remplace my XML code whith yr?

Comment: Yes, with this library you can achieve zoom effects.